# How to change the UI color of Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, interface-design

I recently updated to the 2015 Photoshop CC version. While using it, I realized that I was not particularly pleased with the UI color of the pop-ups/Dialogue boxes that appear(something like the Layer style pop-up).I really liked the color scheme of the previous version.Attaching an image for further reference.

I know that the overall UI color of Photoshop can be changed from preferences, but is there a possibility of changing the dialogue box color also?

Thanks,
Mayank[image]

Comment: The window chrome is controlled by your operating system, not Photoshop.

Comment: Hey..I know that. What I'm talking about is the inside bit. Is there a way to change the UI color for that?

Comment: Uhm.. no.. window chrome is controlled by the operating system. The "inside part" is part of the window chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You cant crack the UI of the software it is defined by the default. You can change the color themes in Photoshop CC, But it wont effect the additional dialog boxes.

There are only Four variations we can get it in Photoshop.

Go Edit>Preferences>Interface, In the dialog box you can find four themes.